Server is blocking sending tickets
I want to add a ticket form on my website (I am using Magento 1.9). The ticket form is from Zoho.
I have added the code:
<script type="text/javascript" nonce="{place_your_nonce_value_here}" src="https://desk.zoho.com/portal/api/web/inapp/954830000000277001?orgId=849940443" defer></script>
When I click on the submit button, I get this error in console:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://desk.zoho.com/portal/api/composetickets?portalId=edbsn4819b1fde9b48121f03c6ad521ec66e49dfee18db46bc47f9d1c82ca0276b4a1' from origin 'https://maxigel.ro' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
efc.15dfad6c7f6c6e7e258b_.js:1
POST https://desk.zoho.com/portal/api/composetickets?portalId=edbsn4819b1fde9b48121f03c6ad521ec66e49dfee18db46bc47f9d1c82ca0276b4a1 net::ERR_FAILED
I assume there is a server configuration that blocks sending the tickets.
Here are the headers from .conf file:
`
    Header always set Feature-Policy "autoplay 'none'"
    Header set Connection keep-alive
    Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
    Header always set Referrer-Policy "same-origin"
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
    Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" env=HTTPS
    Header always set Permissions-Policy "geolocation=(),midi=(),sync-xhr=(),microphone=(),camera=(),magnetometer=(),gyroscope=(),fullscreen=(self),payment=()"
    Header always set Content-Security-Policy "object-src 'none'; upgrade-insecure-requests;"

`
I don't get it what is the problem and how to fix this.

Surely you don't have access to see Zoho's server configuration? If that's your server's configuration, it's irrelevant to the issue

What do you mean by Zoho's server configuration?
I am using Zoho Desk, which is a ticket portal.

Zoho is blocking the request. You can't fix it by changing your server's configuration.

If I put the script on localhost or another server, there is no problem.
When I contacted them on live chat, they said that the error is from my server.
